# Custom Lazy<Deferred<T>> fun leads to frame skipping and crash

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm following the MVVM using ROOM,Retrofit,Koin DI etc. and inside of my MainFragment class i'm calling  my `bindUI()` function that is responsible for fetching data through the viewModel asynchronously using kotlin coroutines as you can see below. Now, when i run my app it crashes almost immediately.

Here's what i tried: I placed a breakpoint inside of `bindUI()` and specifically on my first `.await()` call on `val currentWeather` and run the debugger. I noticed that as soon as the await call is resolved and the result is returned to the variable, the application crashes saying that `Skipped 1501 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` and then `Skipped 359 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Now, why would that be since i'm running those async calls inside of the `Dispathcers.IO` thread and at the moment of the crash i'm only executing one await() call?

Here's my MainFragment class:

```
const val UNIT_SYSTEM_KEY = "UNIT_SYSTEM"

class MainFragment(
    private val weatherUnitConverter: WeatherUnitConverter
) : ScopedFragment() {

    // Lazy inject the view model
    private val viewModel: WeatherViewModel by viewModel()
    private lateinit var unitSystem:String
    private val TAG = MainFragment::class.java.simpleName

    // View declarations
    private lateinit var lcHourlyForecasts: LineChart
    private lateinit var weeklyForecastRCV: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var scrollView: NestedScrollView
    private lateinit var detailsExpandedArrow:ImageView
    private lateinit var detailsExpandedLayout: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var dailyWeatherDetailsHeader:LinearLayout
    private lateinit var settingsBtnImageView:ImageView
    private lateinit var unitSystemImgView:ImageView
    private lateinit var locationTxtView:TextView
    // Current weather view declarations
    private lateinit var currentWeatherDate:TextView
    private lateinit var currentWeatherTemp:TextView
    private lateinit var currentWeatherSummaryText:TextView
    private lateinit var currentWeatherSummaryIcon:ImageView
    private lateinit var currentWeatherPrecipProb:TextView
    // Today/Details weather view declarations
    private lateinit var todayHighLowTemp:TextView
    private lateinit var todayWindSpeed:TextView
    private lateinit var todayFeelsLike:TextView
    private lateinit var todayUvIndex:TextView
    private lateinit var todayPrecipProb:TextView
    private lateinit var todayCloudCover:TextView
    private lateinit var todayHumidity:TextView
    private lateinit var todayPressure:TextView
    private lateinit var todaySunriseTime:TextView
    private lateinit var todaySunsetTime:TextView

    // OnClickListener to handle the current weather's "Details" layout expansion/collapse
    private val onCurrentWeatherDetailsClicked:View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        if(detailsExpandedLayout.visibility == View.GONE) {
            detailsExpandedLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            detailsExpandedArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_up_black)
        }
        else {
            detailsExpandedLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            detailsExpandedArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_down_arrow)
        }
    }

    // OnClickListener to allow navigating from this fragment to the settings one
    private val onSettingsButtonClicked:View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        (activity as MainActivity).openSettingsPage()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
        // View initializations
        scrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.nsv_main)
        lcHourlyForecasts = view.findViewById(R.id.lc_hourly_forecasts)
        detailsExpandedLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_expandable)
        detailsExpandedArrow = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow)
        dailyWeatherDetailsHeader = view.findViewById(R.id.current_weather_details_header)
        dailyWeatherDetailsHeader.setOnClickListener(onCurrentWeatherDetailsClicked)
        settingsBtnImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.settings)
        settingsBtnImageView.setOnClickListener(onSettingsButtonClicked)
        unitSystemImgView = view.findViewById(R.id.unitSystemImg)
        locationTxtView = view.findViewById(R.id.location)
        initCurrentWeatherViews(view)
        initTodayWeatherViews(view)
        // RCV initialization
        weeklyForecastRCV = view.findViewById(R.id.weekly_forecast_rcv)
        weeklyForecastRCV.adapter = WeeklyWeatherAdapter(listOf(),viewModel.preferences, this,weatherUnitConverter) // init the adapter with empty data
        weeklyForecastRCV.setHasFixedSize(true)
        // Disable nested scrolling to control the RCV scrolling via the parent NestedScrollView
        weeklyForecastRCV.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        initLineChart()
        bindUI()
    }


    private fun SharedPreferences.stringLiveData(key: String, defValue: String): SharedPreferenceLiveData<String> {
        return SharedPreferenceStringLiveData(this, key, defValue)
    }

    private fun bindUI() = launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        //TODO:sp get the coordinates dynamically
        viewModel.setLocCoordinates(37.8267,-122.4233)
        // fetch current weather
        val currentWeather = viewModel.currentWeatherData.await()
        // fetch weekly weather
        val weeklyWeather = viewModel.weeklyWeatherEntries.await()
        // fetch the location
        val weatherLocation = viewModel.weatherLocation.await()

        // Observe the location for changes
        weatherLocation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { location ->
            if(location == null) return@Observer
            launch {
                updateLocation(location)
            }
        })

        // Observe the current weather live data
        currentWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {currently ->
            if(currently == null) return@Observer
            setCurrentWeatherDate(currently.time.toDouble())

            // Observe the unit system sharedPrefs live data for changes
            viewModel.preferences.stringLiveData(UNIT_SYSTEM_KEY, UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))
                .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {unitSystem ->
                    when(unitSystem) {
                        UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> {
                            setCurrentWeatherTemp(currently.temperature)
                            setUnitSystemImgView(unitSystem)
                        }
                        UnitSystem.US.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> {
                            setCurrentWeatherTemp(weatherUnitConverter.convertToFahrenheit(
                                currently.temperature
                            ))
                            setUnitSystemImgView(unitSystem)
                        }
                    }
                })

            setCurrentWeatherSummaryText(currently.summary)
            setCurrentWeatherSummaryIcon(currently.icon)
            setCurrentWeatherPrecipProb(currently.precipProbability)
        })

        // observe the weekly weather live data
        weeklyWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {weatherEntries ->
            if(weatherEntries == null) return@Observer
            // update the recyclerView with the new data
            (weeklyForecastRCV.adapter as WeeklyWeatherAdapter).updateWeeklyWeatherData(weatherEntries)
            initTodayData(weatherEntries[0])
        })
    }

    /**
     * Uses the location param's lat & longt values
     * to determine the selected location and updates
     * the view.
     */
    private suspend fun updateLocation(location: WeatherLocation) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val geocoder = Geocoder(activity,Locale.getDefault())
            try {
                val addr = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude,location.longitude,1)
                val adobj = addr[0]
                locationTxtView.text =  adobj.countryName
            } catch (e:IOException) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.printStackTrace().toString())
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the views for the current weather.
     */
    private fun initCurrentWeatherViews(view: View) {
        currentWeatherDate = view.findViewById(R.id.current_weather_date)
        currentWeatherTemp = view.findViewById(R.id.current_temp_main)
        currentWeatherSummaryText = view.findViewById(R.id.current_weather_summary_text)
        currentWeatherSummaryIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.current_weather_summary_icon)
        currentWeatherPrecipProb = view.findViewById(R.id.current_weather_precip_text)
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the views for the Detailed Today weather view.
     */
    private fun initTodayWeatherViews(view: View?) {
        if(view == null) return
        todayHighLowTemp = view.findViewById(R.id.today_lowHighTemp)
        todayWindSpeed = view.findViewById(R.id.today_windSpeed)
        todayFeelsLike = view.findViewById(R.id.today_feelsLike)
        todayUvIndex = view.findViewById(R.id.today_uvIndex)
        todayPrecipProb = view.findViewById(R.id.today_precipProb)
        todayCloudCover = view.findViewById(R.id.today_cloudCover)
        todayHumidity = view.findViewById(R.id.today_humidity)
        todayPressure = view.findViewById(R.id.today_pressure)
        todaySunriseTime = view.findViewById(R.id.today_sunriseTime)
        todaySunsetTime = view.findViewById(R.id.today_sunsetTime)
    }

    private fun setUnitSystemImgView(unitSystem:String) {
        val resource = when(unitSystem) {
            UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                -> R.drawable.ic_celsius
            UnitSystem.US.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                -> R.drawable.ic_fahrenheit
            else -> R.drawable.ic_celsius
        }
        unitSystemImgView.setImageResource(resource)
    }

    /**
     * Links the data to the view for the Today(Details) Weather View.
     */
    private fun initTodayData(weekDayWeatherEntry: WeekDayWeatherEntry) {
        // Observe the unit system sharedPrefs live data for changes
        viewModel.preferences.stringLiveData(UNIT_SYSTEM_KEY, UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {unitSystem ->
                when(unitSystem) {
                    UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> {
                        setTodayWeatherLowHighTemp(weekDayWeatherEntry.temperatureLow,weekDayWeatherEntry.temperatureHigh)
                        setTodayWeatherWindSpeed(weekDayWeatherEntry.windSpeed,unitSystem)
                        setTodayWeatherFeelsLike(weekDayWeatherEntry.apparentTemperatureLow,weekDayWeatherEntry.apparentTemperatureHigh)
                    }
                    UnitSystem.US.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> {
                        setTodayWeatherLowHighTemp(weatherUnitConverter.convertToFahrenheit(
                            weekDayWeatherEntry.temperatureLow),
                            weatherUnitConverter.convertToFahrenheit(
                            weekDayWeatherEntry.temperatureHigh))
                        setTodayWeatherWindSpeed(weatherUnitConverter.convertToMiles(weekDayWeatherEntry.windSpeed),unitSystem)
                        setTodayWeatherFeelsLike(weatherUnitConverter.convertToFahrenheit(
                            weekDayWeatherEntry.apparentTemperatureLow)
                            ,weatherUnitConverter.convertToFahrenheit(weekDayWeatherEntry.apparentTemperatureHigh))
                    }
                }
            })
        setTodayWeatherUvIndex(weekDayWeatherEntry.uvIndex)
        setTodayWeatherPrecipProb(weekDayWeatherEntry.precipProbability)
        setTodayWeatherCloudCover(weekDayWeatherEntry.cloudCover)
        setTodayWeatherHumidity(weekDayWeatherEntry.humidity)
        setTodayWeatherPressure(weekDayWeatherEntry.pressure)
        setTodayWeatherSunriseTime(weekDayWeatherEntry.sunriseTime)
        setTodayWeatherSunsetTime(weekDayWeatherEntry.sunsetTime)
    }
...
}
```

WeatherViewModel.kt:

```
class WeatherViewModel(
    private val forecastRepository: ForecastRepository,
    context:Context
) : ViewModel() {

    private var mLatitude:Double = 0.0
    private var mLongitute:Double = 0.0
    private val appContext = context.applicationContext
    // Retrieve the sharedPrefs
    val preferences:SharedPreferences
        get() = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)

    // This will run only when currentWeatherData is called from the View
    val currentWeatherData by lazyDeferred {
        forecastRepository.getCurrentWeather(mLatitude, mLongitute)
    }

    val weeklyWeatherEntries by lazyDeferred {
        val currentDateEpoch = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()
        forecastRepository.getWeekDayWeatherList(mLatitude, mLongitute, currentDateEpoch)
    }

    val weatherLocation by lazyDeferred {
        forecastRepository.getWeatherLocation()
    }

    fun setLocCoordinates(latitude:Double,longitude:Double) {
        mLatitude = latitude
        mLongitute = longitude
    }
}
```

Here's my custom `Lazy<Deferred<T>>` fun inside of my Delegates.kt file:

```
fun<T> lazyDeferred(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T) : Lazy<Deferred<T>> {
    return lazy {
        GlobalScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            block.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my repository class just in case:

```
private const val WEEKLY_FORECAST_DAYS_COUNT = 7

/**
 * The Repository class responsible
 * for caching the downloaded weather data
 * and for swapping between different data sources.
 */
class ForecastRepositoryImpl(
    private val currentWeatherDao: CurrentWeatherDao,
    private val weekDayWeatherDao: WeekDayWeatherDao,
    private val weatherLocationDao: WeatherLocationDao,
    private val locationProvider: LocationProvider,
    private val weatherNetworkDataSource: WeatherNetworkDataSource
) : ForecastRepository {

    init {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.apply {
            // Persist downloaded data
            downloadedCurrentWeatherData.observeForever { newCurrentWeather: CurrentWeatherResponse? ->
                persistFetchedCurrentWeather(newCurrentWeather!!)
            }
            downloadedWeeklyWeatherData.observeForever { newWeeklyWeather: WeeklyWeatherResponse? ->
                persistFetchedWeeklyWeather(newWeeklyWeather!!)
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getCurrentWeather(latitude:Double,longitude:Double): LiveData<CurrentWeatherEntry> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            initWeatherData(latitude,longitude)
            return@withContext currentWeatherDao.getCurrentWeather()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getWeekDayWeatherList(latitude: Double,longitude: Double,time:Long): LiveData<out List<WeekDayWeatherEntry>> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            initWeatherData(latitude,longitude)
            return@withContext weekDayWeatherDao.getFutureWeather(time)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getWeatherLocation(): LiveData<WeatherLocation> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@withContext weatherLocationDao.getWeatherLocation()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initWeatherData(latitude:Double,longitude:Double) {
        // retrieve the last weather location from room
        val lastWeatherLocation = weatherLocationDao.getWeatherLocation().value

        if(lastWeatherLocation == null ||
                locationProvider.hasLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)) { // then this is the first time we are launching the app
            fetchCurrentWeather()
            fetchWeeklyWeather()
            return
        }

        if(isFetchCurrentNeeded(lastWeatherLocation.zonedDateTime))
            fetchCurrentWeather()

        if(isFetchWeeklyNeeded())
            fetchWeeklyWeather()
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the current weather data should be re-fetched.
     * @param lastFetchedTime The time at which the current weather data were last fetched
     * @return True or false respectively
     */
    private fun isFetchCurrentNeeded(lastFetchedTime: ZonedDateTime) : Boolean {
        val thirtyMinutesAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30)
        return lastFetchedTime.isBefore(thirtyMinutesAgo)
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the Current Weather data from the WeatherNetworkDataSource.
     */
    private suspend fun fetchCurrentWeather() {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentWeather(
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLat(),
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLong()
        )
    }

    private fun isFetchWeeklyNeeded(): Boolean {
        val todayEpochTime = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()
        val futureWeekDayCount = weekDayWeatherDao.countFutureWeekDays(todayEpochTime)
        return futureWeekDayCount < WEEKLY_FORECAST_DAYS_COUNT
    }

    private suspend fun fetchWeeklyWeather() {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.fetchWeeklyWeather(
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLat(),
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationLong()
        )
    }

    /**
     * Caches the downloaded current weather data to the local
     * database.
     * @param fetchedCurrentWeather The most recently fetched current weather data
     */
    private fun persistFetchedCurrentWeather(fetchedCurrentWeather:CurrentWeatherResponse) {
        // Using a GlobalScope since a Repository class doesn't have a lifecycle
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // cache the data
            currentWeatherDao.upsert(fetchedCurrentWeather.currentWeatherEntry)
            weatherLocationDao.upsert(fetchedCurrentWeather.location)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches the downloaded weekly weather data to the local
     * database.
     * @param fetchedWeeklyWeather  The most recently fetched weekly weather data
     */
    private fun persistFetchedWeeklyWeather(fetchedWeeklyWeather: WeeklyWeatherResponse) {

        fun deleteOldData() {
            val time = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()
            weekDayWeatherDao.deleteOldEntries(time)
        }

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            deleteOldData()
            val weekDayEntriesList = fetchedWeeklyWeather.weeklyWeatherContainer.weekDayEntries
            weekDayWeatherDao.insert(weekDayEntriesList)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the crash log i found out about earlier today:

```
2020-04-13 01:43:48.628 26875-26904/com.nesoinode.flogaweather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
    Process: com.nesoinode.flogaweather, PID: 26875
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.db.entity.WeatherLocation.getId()' on a null object reference
        at com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.db.dao.WeatherLocationDao_Impl$1.bind(WeatherLocationDao_Impl.java:34)
        at com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.db.dao.WeatherLocationDao_Impl$1.bind(WeatherLocationDao_Impl.java:26)
        at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:63)
        at com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.db.dao.WeatherLocationDao_Impl.upsert(WeatherLocationDao_Impl.java:52)
        at com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.repository.ForecastRepositoryImpl$persistFetchedCurrentWeather$1.invokeSuspend(ForecastRepositoryImpl.kt:131)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:561)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:727)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:667)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:655)
```

It's pointing to this part of my repository class as the root cause. I can't tell why though.

```
private fun persistFetchedCurrentWeather(fetchedCurrentWeather:CurrentWeatherResponse) {
    // Using a GlobalScope since a Repository class doesn't have a lifecycle
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // cache the data
        currentWeatherDao.upsert(fetchedCurrentWeather.currentWeatherEntry)
        weatherLocationDao.upsert(fetchedCurrentWeather.location)
    }
}
```

UPDATE #2:

CurrentWeatherEntry :

```
const val CURRENT_WEATHER_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeatherEntry(
    val time: Long, // epoch timestamp
    val icon: String,
    val summary: String,
    val precipProbability: Double,
    val temperature: Double
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id:Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
}
```

WeatherLocation:

```
const val WEATHER_LOCATION_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "weather_location")
data class WeatherLocation(
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double,
    val timezone: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id:Int = WEATHER_LOCATION_ID

    private var epochTimeVal:Long = 0

    val zonedDateTime:ZonedDateTime
        get() {
            val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(this.epochTimeVal)
            val zoneId = ZoneId.of(timezone)
            return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant,zoneId)
        }

    fun setEpochTimeVal(time:Long) {
        this.epochTimeVal = time}
    fun getEpochTimeVal() : Long = epochTimeVal
}
```

and CurrentWeatherResponse:

```
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
    // Tells GSON that the "currently" field of the JSON returned by the
    // API should be tied with our CurrentWeatherEntry data class
    @SerializedName("currently")
    val currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry,
    @Embedded
    val location: WeatherLocation
) {
    init {
        location.setEpochTimeVal(currentWeatherEntry.time)
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't your DAO functions already `suspend fun`s? They don't need any `withContext` around them. On top of that, your `lazyDeferred` uses `GlobalScope` and thus the `Default ` dispatcher so the DAO calls are twice removed from the UI thread. Couldn't it be that the very act of using the debugger causes those "N frames skipped" warnings, and the crash itself is of a completely different origin? BTW, `return@withContext` is superfluous. The final expression in a block determines its return value.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Actually no, my DAO functions are normal ones. Is it a better practice to define them as `suspend fun`? Which scope should my `lazyDeferred` be using?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you were also right about the crash. I've updated my post.

Comment: I don't think you have any other choice but `GlobalScope` for the initializers, but you can use the `Main` dispatcher. This is just for the top-level code anyawy, and if the DAOs are declared as suspendable, they'll use Room's own internal dispatcher so you eliminate that concern from your code entirely.

Comment: Check your DAO code, you're returning `CurrentWeatherResponse` with `location == null`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The `location` field that you see in my updated post (Added the daos & entities), is an `@Embedded` field because `CurrentWeatherResponse` actually returns a `latitude`,`longitude` and `timezone` field but i've put those inside of `WeatherLocation`. I'm also trying to pass a value (`time`) from the `currently` field/Entity of the `CurrentWeatherResponse` to my `WeatherLocation` field. Could there be an issue with the embedded class causing it to be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the further diagnosis you made, the problem is unrelated to `lazyDeferred`, blocking the main thread, or coroutines in general. Your `CurrentWeatherDao` sometimes returns a `CurrentWeatherResponse` with  `location == null`.

Comment: I used a `LoggingInterceptor` on my OkHttp client in my APIService class to log the request and its body. Both work fine and the location data is successfully retrieved. As i mentioned though, the `CurrentWeatherResponse` originally would return a `CurrentWeatherEntry` field and then a `latitude`,`longitude`,`offset` & `timezone` fields which i've placed into my `WeatherLocation` entity. I've used the @Embedded annotation in the `CurrentWeatherResponse` so i don't see how those values wouldn't be passed to the location entity. Even the database inspector shows those values as not null

Answer (score 1):

You never specified where `forecastRepository.getWeatherLocation()` should be executed so it gets executed on the dispatcher of your `bindUI` function which is `Dispatchers.Main`.
This means the request blocks your UI thread and causes the warning you're seeing in the log.

You need to specify that it executes on a separate dispatcher so the UI can continue updating normally:

```kotlin
lazyDeferred {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        forecastRepository.getWeatherLocation()
    }
}
```

As a separate issue, your `lazyDeferred` is slightly redundant in that it is "double"-lazy. You could remove the outer `Lazy<T>` and it would still work exactly the same way, or remove the `start = CoroutineStart.LAZY` and have the result arrive slightly sooner. (This essentially depends on whether the request starts when the `Lazy` is resolved, or when `Deferred.await` is called)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm probably confused here but in my repository class don't i specify the context for the execution of `forecastRepository.getWeatherLocation()` to be `Dispatchers.IO` using `withContext{}`? I tried specifying it in my viewModel too as per your answer and it seems to have decreased the frames skipped to ~150 and now it's only logged once. Yet, i'm still not sure what's different for getWeatherLocation that doesn't already apply to `getCurrentWeather` and `getWeekDayWeatherList`. I'm doing the same things there, should i also specify the context again in the viewmodel?